# Publishing EAR file hangs on WebSphere 8.0

Tags: java, websphere, ear, websphere-8

Recently some of our projects started hanging when publishing to WebSphere 8.0 (tested with 8.0.0.5, 8.0.0.6 and 8.0.0.9), but this doesn't happen all the times.

This is a normal installation details

```
Installing...
If there are enterprise beans in the application, the EJB deployment process can take several minutes. Do not save the configuration until the process completes.
Check the SystemOut.log on the deployment manager or server where the application is deployed for specific information about the EJB deployment process as it occurs.
ADMA5016I: Installation of ImagesServerEAR started.
ADMA5067I: Resource validation for application ImagesServerEAR completed successfully.
ADMA5058I: Application and module versions are validated with versions of deployment targets.
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5081I: The bootstrap address for client module is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5053I: The library references for the installed optional package are created.
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5001I: The application binaries are saved in C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv11\wstemp\92668751\workspace\cells\SRV-CLI-DEVNode11Cell\applications\ImagesServerEAR.ear\ImagesServerEAR.ear
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
SECJ0400I: Successfully updated the application ImagesServerEAR with the appContextIDForSecurity information.
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5005I: The application ImagesServerEAR is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5113I: Activation plan created successfully.
ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application ImagesServerEAR is complete.
ADMA5013I: Application ImagesServerEAR installed successfully.
Application ImagesServerEAR installed successfully.
To start the application, first save changes to the master configuration.
Changes have been made to your local configuration. You can: 
•  Save directly to the master configuration. 
•  Review changes before saving or discarding.
```

But when the deploy hangs, the logs only show this

```
Installing...
If there are enterprise beans in the application, the EJB deployment process can take several minutes. Do not save the configuration until the process completes.
Check the SystemOut.log on the deployment manager or server where the application is deployed for specific information about the EJB deployment process as it occurs.
ADMA5016I: Installation of ImagesServerEAR started.
ADMA5067I: Resource validation for application ImagesServerEAR completed successfully.
```

and the CPU goes to 100% on 4 out of the 8 cores.

There isn't anything else logged anywhere.

Any ideas on what can be causing this?

Comment: Do you have anything suspicious in logs?

Comment: No, nothing is logged to SystemOut.log or SystemErr.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by increasing the amount of the HEAP size

Answer (score 1):

Increase the deployment manager heap size by going to:

1. System Administration -> Deployment Manager
2. Server Infrastructure -> Java and Process Management -> Process Definition
3. Additional Properties -> Java Virtual Machine

Default Maximum heap size is 256MB for Websphere 8, so set a higher value e.g. 512MB.

You can also check the deployment manager logs here to confirm it is cause by a heap error

*was_dir*/profiles/autoWasDmgr/logs/dmgr/SystemOut.log